# Quantity based discounts for bulk-buying products

Tags: logic

I hope I can get the math community to help me on this. I understand that this is a very beginner level type question but I don't know where to start.

Some background: my father owns a packaging business, and has done so for 38+ years. He's been in charge of the prices and the company has been doing well, but at 72 (and quite stubborn) he seems to have made a few errors recently.

I've recently joined his firm and started as manager, until today he was in charge of pricing, but I've decided to take this on myself now.

We sell bags and boxes. We're unique in the trade in that we will sell you individual items, whereas our competitors demand you buy a full box / crate / pallet load at a time.

So, we charge a price for these individual items based on their cost price, and if the customer buys more then depending on the product, they get a discount depending on how many they buy.

We have one product where they can buy it individually, but if they buy 100 (this particular products is banded in 100's) then they get a 15% discount. If they buy a full box of 600 then they get a 30% discount. More if they 10 full boxes, say 50% off the single unit price.

The problem is, my Dad has not been very careful.

There is one particular product that costs 46 pence each, but if you order 25 the price goes down to 39p (-15%), 100 is 31p each (-33%) and 600 is 23p each (-50%).

**The problem** is when you order 450 of these. They would cost you £139.50. If you were to add 600 to your cart then the cost to the customer is less, at £138! Which is ludicrous.

We have many products where this happens.

I'd like to know if there is a single formula that can be applied to prevent this kind of mistake from happening?

Or perhaps, it's as simple as a percentage level we shouldn't go over? I really don't know. Math is absolutely not my strong point. Any pointers, methods, or advice is obviously really appreciated, we desperately need some help in figuring this out.

It simply cannot be right that when you order more of an item, it becomes cheaper. The unit price can go down, of course, but not like this.

The above product is priced like this:

Quantity / Bulk Purchase Pricing
25 - 99 / £0.39 each
100 - 599 / £0.31 each
600 - 1199 / £0.23 each
1200 or more /£0.18 each

Comment: Mauro - I've edited my question to include this particular product's pricing structure.

Comment: I suggest that the discounts are applied to the number of items exceeding each cut-off. I.e., items $1$ to $24$ cost 46p each, items $25$ to $99$ cost 39p each, items $100$ to $599$ cost 31p each and items $600+$ cost 23p each. So, if I wanted to buy $1000$ items, I would pay $46 \times 24 + 39 \times 74 + 31 \times 499 + 23 \times 400 = 28\ 659$. So, each item would cost me, on average, just under 29p. Edit: I noted that your edit says basically my suggestion. By the way, are you using an excel sheet for the computation?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to define a branched function with the price in pounds $p$ as a function of the quantity ordered $q$:
$$
p(q) = \left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  0.46 q & \textrm{if} \ q \leq 24 \\
  0.39 q + 1.68 & \textrm{if} \ 25 \leq q \leq 99 \\
  0.31 q + 9.60 & \textrm{if} \ 100 \leq q \leq 599 \\
  0.23 q + 57.52 & \textrm{if} \ 600 \leq q \leq 1199 \\
  0.18 q + 117.47 & \textrm{if} \ q \geq 1200
 \end{array}
\right.
$$

I'll present some examples for clarity, with $q$ in units and $p$ in £:
$$
\begin{array}{r|r}
q & p(q) \\
\hline 
1 & 0.46 \\
24 & 11.04 \\
25 & 11.43 \\
99 & 40.29 \\
100 & 40.60 \\
599 & 195.29 \\
600 & 195.52 \\
1\ 199 & 333.29 \\
1\ 200 & 333.47 \\
2\ 000 & 477.47 \\
10\ 000 & 1\ 917.47 \\
\end{array}
$$

These values for $p(q)$ seem to me that are higher than those in your post.

---

A different approach may rely on defining a function for the unitary cost such that the total cost increases.

A function for the unitary cost $u(q)$, inspired in the values you provided, but that is not equal to what you wrote in your post can be, for instance:
$$
u(q) = 0.18 + \frac{0.28}{1 + \frac{q}{100}} = \frac{46 + 0.18q}{100 + q}
$$
When the quantity is small, the unitary price is close to $0.18+0.28 = 0.46$ and then the quantity is large the price is close to $0.18$.

And the total price to pay $p(q)$ is given by:
$$
p(q) = u(q) \times q = 0.18q + \frac{0.28q}{1 + \frac{q}{100}} = \frac{46q + 0.18q^2}{100 + q}
$$

This function gives the following prices (rounded to 4 decimal places):
$$
\begin{array}{r|r|r}
q & u(q) \  & p(q) \quad \\
\hline 
1 & 0.4572 & 0.4572 \\
24 & 0.4058 & 9.7394 \\
25 & 0.4040 & 10.1000 \\
99 & 0.3207 & 31.7496 \\
100 & 0.3200 & 32.0000 \\
599 & 0.2201 & 131.8143 \\
600 & 0.2200 & 132.0000 \\
1\ 199 & 0.2016 & 241.6645 \\
1\ 200 & 0.2015 & 241.8462 \\
2\ 000 & 0.1913 & 386.6667 \\
10\ 000 & 0.1828 & 1\ 827.7228 \\
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there's a more fundamental problem here. Forget the current numbers for the moment, and consider the difference between buying 599 of the product vs buying 600 of the product. Surely, the discount **per individual item** is larger if you buy 600, vs if you buy 599. Because the numbers are so close to each other, it's hard to make it so that the total price would be higher when you're buying 600 vs buying 599.

You should switch up the whole rule of calculating the discount: You could apply the discount not to all of the items, but the items that are added **in addition to** the limiting number. Let's say that the first $25$ are at a normal price of 46p, and after that you get a $15$ per cent discount for every item that added after that. Then, to buy 40 of these would cost
$$
25 \times 46p + (40-25)(1-0.15)\times 46p = 17.365
$$
How about this kind of approach?

Comment: That's a good idea, but is not going to be practical in this case, unfortunately. We have an accounts package and a website where certain rules apply, so the price has to apply to all units, not in the tiered way you propose.